# Freeze Columns in Vaadin 7 table

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have 20 columns in a vaadin 7 table, I want to freeze 4 columns so that whenever we scroll horizontally we should be able to see those frozen columns always.

Answer (score 0):

There is no freeze columns feature in Vaadin 7 Table. But in newer Grid component you can set the X left most columns to be frozen with Grid.setFrozenColumnCount(..) methdod, see more here:

https://vaadin.com/api/framework/7.7.14/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html#setFrozenColumnCount-int-

If you want to do something similar with Vaadin 7 Table, you probably need to do the following

- Use two tables with the same data source Container
- Wrap them inside e.g. CssLayout
- Give z-index to other Table so that it is placed on top of the other in your theme CSS styles (Table.addStyleName("frozen-columns-table"))
- Set the Table on top have only the "frozen" columns with setVisibleColumns(..) method
- Set/style column widths etc. accordingly. The Table on top needs to be narrower than the bottom Table.

The above approach has its limitations and performance impacts, but could be a solution in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but to be more specific  I am using vaadin 7.2.6 this doesn't have the com.vaadin.ui.Grid setFrozenColumnCount API. Could please suggest how I can do this in Vaadin 7.2.6? Thanks.

Comment: There is no such built in feature in Vaadin 7 Table. 7.2.6 is very old version, I would recommend to update some newer version if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will try to update it to the newer version.